# How to bypass next.js one page framework behavior?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

Is there a way to make next.js not work like a one page framework and open every URL with reload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to use this behavior, but It's depending on your navigation method.

If you want to navigation with hard reload.

With HTML use `anchor` tag instead of Next.js `Link` element.

```
<a href="/about" />
```

Programatically with `js` use `window.location.href` instead of Nuxt.js `router`

```
window.location.href = "/about"
```